# How to build a window executable bin for linux project

Tags: mingw-w64

I have a project writen with C99. It links to `libcurl`, generate makefile with cmake. Now, i want to explore the project to window env. I tried cygwin first, everything works except that final user need to install cygwin too.

After some search, mingw64 may archive my goal (build and use directly in window), but i could not find a full use guild for how to build linux project with mingw64 in ubuntu(linux).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, a solutions works:

1. install window cmake
2. install mingw-w64
3. mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
4. mingw32-make

MinGW may not support all API, some compatible job should be done.